# Back button stay after setActiveItem on a Ext.navigation.View

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a Ext.navigation.View and i want to get back when i click on a button, so i made this code in my controller :

```
this.getBuzz().setActiveItem(0);
```

It works, but the back button stay in the navigation bar, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setActiveItem()` is not designed to be used in `Ext.navigation.View`

Basically you don't need to attach listeners for your Back button, see this for more details: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View

And in fact, the method which is called when navigating back is: `yourView.pop()`

Comment: How can i get my previous view?

Comment: I got my answer, i have just to use : this.getBuzz().pop();